# Отразить (развернуть) pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть pandas.DataFrame,в котором более 1000 уникальных имен и диапазон дат более месяца.

| Name | date | price | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ручка | 2023-10-13 05:00:00 | 10 | 5 |
| Стол | 2023-10-13 05:00:00 | 15 | 1 |
| Ручка | 2023-10-16 07:00:00 | 11 | 3 |
| Стол | 2023-10-9 02:00:00 | 44 | 6 |

Его необходимо преобразовать в следующий вид:

| Name | series_type | 2023-10-9 02:00:00 | 2023-10-16 07:00:00 | 2023-10-13 05:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ручка | price | nan | 11 | 10 |
| Ручка | total_sales | nan | 3 | 5 |
| Стол | price | 44 | nan | 15 |
| Стол | total_sales | 6 | nan | 1 |

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать функцию, которая сделает такое преобразование.

На данный момент я иду по следующему пути, но зашел в тупик:

```
def transpose_df(df):
       # Нахожу все возможные даты которые передам в качестве названия колонок     
       start = df.date.min()
       end = df.date.max() 
       total_hours = int((end-start).days * 24 + (end-start).seconds/60/60)
       date_coll = [(start + timedelta(hours=x))
           .strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H') for x in range(0, total_hours)]

       # Создаю пустой df с необходимым типом колонок
       df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=[['name', 'series_type'] + date_coll], 
                                                               dtype='datetime64[ns]')
       df_new[['name', 'series_type']] = df_test[['name', 'series_type']].astype(object)  

    for nameDF in df.name.unique():
        
       # Создаю два словаря
       price_now = dict(
                 zip(list(map(str, df_analyze.date[df_analyze.name 
                                             == nameDF].tolist())), 
                      df_analyze.price[df_analyze.name == nameDF]))
       sales_now = dict(
                  zip(list(map(str, df_analyze.date[df_analyze.name 
                                             == nameDF].tolist())), 
                df_analyze.total_sales[df_analyze.name == nameDF]))

        # Добавляю к ним 
        price_now.update({'name':nameDF, 'series_type':'prise'})
        sales_now.update({'name':nameDF, 
                         'series_type':'total_sales'})
    
        df_new = df_new.append(price_now, ignore_index=True)
        df_new = df_new.append(sales_now, ignore_index=True)
    
  return df_new
```

Получаю ошибку

```
---> 22    df_new = df_new.append(price_now, ignore_index=True)
ValueError: no types given
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй комбинацию [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) и [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Ручка', 'Стол', 'Ручка', 'Стол'],
                   'date': ['2023-10-13 05:00:00', '2023-10-13 05:00:00',
                            '2023-10-16 07:00:00', '2023-10-9 02:00:00'],
                   'price': [10, 15, 11, 44],
                   'total_sales': [5, 1, 3, 6]})

def transpose_df(data):   
    df = data.melt(
        id_vars=['Name', 'date'],
        var_name='series_type').pivot(
            index=['Name', 'series_type'],
            columns='date', values='value').reset_index()
    return df

print(transpose_df(df))
```

Вывод:

```
    Name    series_type 2023-10-13 05:00:00 2023-10-16 07:00:00 2023-10-9 02:00:00
0   Ручка   price          10.0                  11.0               NaN
1   Ручка   total_sales     5.0                   3.0               NaN
2   Стол    price          15.0                   NaN              44.0
3   Стол    total_sales     1.0                   NaN               6.0
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Можно воспользоваться методом melt() непосредственно фрейма и избежать перепаковки в новый фрейм `return df.melt(id_vars=['Name', 'date'], var_name='series_type').pivot(index=['Name', 'series_type'], columns='date', values='value').reset_index()`

Comment: Поправил в ответе, так действительно выглядит аккуратнее